# Can not get xmlhttp response on local server

Tags: json, jquery

I am trying to get xmlhttp request from my server, running on local machine.

```
  function makeRequest(url) {

    var url = "http://localhost:8081/data/json";

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.send();

    function alertContents() {
        if ( request.readyState === 4 )  {
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            alert(jsonResponse.computedString);
            alert(request.status);
        }
    }

}
```

But it always returns status=0.

I can't figure out why does this happen.

Comment: What is the code that generates `data.json`. What is expected to be in `data.json`

Comment: It's just file with data in JSON representation. Something like this:
http://pastebin.com/JwLdVx92

Comment: Have you tried using `this` instead of `request` inside `alertContents()`?

Comment: I also recommend actually writing it to a jQuery ajax request. eg: `$.get(url, alertContents, 'json');` [more info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). You're gonna have to rewrite the `alertContents` function a little bit: `var alertContents = function(data) { alert(data); }`

Comment: > Have you tried using this instead of request inside alertContents()?
Yes. It does not help.

Comment: What host and port are you using to access the page initially?  If they aren't the same, you may be running into a [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) policy issue

Comment: Yes. You are right. I cannot use a different port, even when using the same domain.
I think using [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) will be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion above it appears that the problem is a same origin policy issue. Even when hitting the same server you can run into this if the

- protocols (http vs https)
- hosts (localhost vs 127.0.0.1)
- ports (80 vs 8081) don't match.

Console output and Chrome's network tab (CTRL+SHIFT+J) can be helpful in diagnosing problems like this as well.